# ¿Cómo puedo remover variables si no están definidas?

Tags: php

Estoy con un problema en el renderizado de variables predefinidas. He creado un simple script donde busca `{valor}` y lo devuelve como variable para renderizar en una plantilla de email.

El script funciona perfectamente, el problema es que quiero remover `{notExist}` si no está definido.

Respuesta:

> Hi Matias, We receive your inquiry as soon as possible we will reply
>   your message. {notExist}

Código PHP:

```
<?php
public function renderEmail($var=null,$templateHTML=null){
if(is_array($var) && $var!=null && $templateHTML!=null ){

foreach($var as $key => $value) {
$templateHTML = str_replace("{".$key."}", $value, $templateHTML);

}
return $templateHTML;
}
}



$vars = [
'name' => 'Matias'
];

$templateHTML = 'Hi {name},
We receive your inquiry as soon as possible we will reply your message.

{notExist} ';

$test = $this->renderEmail($vars,$templateHTML);

echo $test;
```

Comment: Aunque es posible hacer lo que pides creo que lo estás enfocando mal. Deberías crear la matriz de valores con todas las variables predefinidas como una cadena vacía e ir modificando en ellas su valor. Por ejemplo: `$vars = [ 'name' => 'Matias', 'notExist' => '' ];`. Voy redactando la respuesta con el código que solicitas.

Comment: claro si eso si lo se el tema seria lo siguiente enci si la variable no existe que no se muestre por ejemplo si probas el código,  con una variable que no este definida en la matriz del array te la ajora yo quería hacer que no muestre las matrices que no este definidas.

Comment: Tal y como te dije, he terminado la redacción de la respuesta. Espero que sea lo que estabas buscando.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para limpiar las variables encerradas entre llaves `{}` que quedaron sin sustituir bastaría con usar [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/preg_replace) para sustituir el patrón por una cadena vacía:

```
preg_replace('/{([[:alpha:]]*)}/', '', $templateHTML)
```

Por lo que tu método podría quedar así:

```
function renderEmail($var = null, $templateHTML = null) {
  /* Si $var es una matriz no puede valer al mismo tiempo null */
  if (is_array($var) && $templateHTML != null) {
    foreach($var as $key => $value) {
      $templateHTML = str_replace("{" . $key . "}", $value, $templateHTML);
    }
    /* Devolvemos la cadena eliminando cualquier texto entre llaves restante */
    return preg_replace('/{[[:alpha:]]*}/', '', $templateHTML);
  }
}
```

La expresión regular `{[[:alpha:]]*}` busca todo aquello que comience por una apertura de llaves y continúe con una serie de caracteres alfanuméricos (`[:alpha:]`) seguido por un cierre de llave.

La anterior respuesta puede consultarse [en el historial de ediciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/237859/1).

Comment: Excelente gracias por tu ayuda anda perfecto :)

Comment: Un placer haber sido de ayuda :)

Comment: Se me ha ocurrido otra solución alternativa más eficaz con `preg_replace`. Editaré mi respuesta en unos minutos con ella.

Comment: Dale perfecto! lo revisare en cuanto este tu actualizacion, si sabia preg_replace es mas eficaz.

Comment: Edición hecha ;)